# Highest award for sports in worldwide

Tags: history, international-sports, awards

Which is the highest award for sports in **worldwide**?
Is there anything for separate sports (like Cricket)?
Or anything like *worldwide award*?

Comment: Why not consider the Olympics as such?

Comment: @Saariko - They do not include all sports.

Comment: You seem to have two questions here. "Which is the highest award for sports **worldwide**?" and "Which is the highest award in individual sports?" Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **[Laureus World Sports Awards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laureus_World_Sports_Awards)** are awarded annually to sportspeople who have been outstanding during the previous year. The awards are given globally.

If we talk about cricket, awards given by ICC (i.e. [**ICC Awards**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_Awards)) are the highest awards for cricket. Also [**Wisden Cricketers of the Year**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wisden_Cricketers_of_the_Year) is also considered one of highest awards.